# How To declare a enum from a list of structs?

Tags: rust, struct, enums, macros

Is it possible to declare a enum from a list of struct declarations and also contain them as their variants?

Like so (unwrapped):

```rust
struct CommandA {
    // --snip--
}

struct CommandB {
    // --snip--
}

enum Commands {
  CommandA(CommandA),
  CommandB(CommandB),
}
```

My goal is to use structs to declare commands for a serial protocol, and not have to declare repeated types (the rest I have figured out).

I would like to do something like this:

```rust
#[derive(Command)]
#[repr(C, packed(1))]
struct CommandA {
  // --snip--
}


#[derive(Command)]
#[repr(C, packed(1))]
struct CommandB {
  // --snip--
}
```

Or something with a macro_rules also would be great.

The reason for not using a `trait Command {}` is because one of the protocol 'users' will be `no_std` (a micro controller), so I cant use `Box<dyn Command>` and the enum acts as 'catch-all' container for the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mimic this behavior with macros. The downside is that this requires implementing all the structs in a single place.

```rust
macro_rules! enum_of_structs {
    ($(#[$($emeta:meta),*])*
    $evis:vis enum $name:ident { 
        $($(#[$($smeta:meta),*])*
        $svis:vis $strct:ident {
            $($fvis:vis $field:ident : $ty:ty),* $(,)? 
        }),* $(,)?
    }) => {
        $(#[$($emeta),*])*
        $evis enum $name {
            $($strct($strct)),*
        }
        $(
        $(#[$($smeta),*])*
        $svis struct $strct {
            $($fvis $field: $ty),*
        })*
    };
}
```

Example of usage:

```rust
enum_of_structs! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    enum Command {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        #[derive(Clone)]
        pub CommandA {
            pub field1: u32,
            field2: String,
        },
        #[derive(Debug)]
        CommandB {
            field2: usize,
        }
    }
}
```

See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b71d6c075fb469f28ddb8932b0b16699).

Comment: Huh, I didn't thought of wrapping `structs` in a `enum`, but in retrospect it makes sense. Is it _possible_ to have the macro declare it from a list of declarations?

Comment: @Luctins note that, even though the syntax is like of an enum, this macro actually does what you want. The syntax is custom (I just made it similar to Rust's syntax).

Comment: Also, having all of the declarations on the same place is a understandable tradeoff for this purpose.

Comment: @Luctins also note the slight differences: within that macro, you can also add meta tags (`#[...]`) and visibility qualifiers to the structs that will be generated.

Comment: yes, I understand. I'm just now trying to understand what you did for future reference (and to be able to do it myself someday). I used something similar a while ago to declare nested structs with `strucstruck` (though that is a procmacro).